# Is there a teleconverter to go between Sony Alpha A77 D and Tamron 70-200 f2.8 (with Sony mount)?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, sony, tamron, teleconverter

I'm struggling to figure out whether there's a teleconverter (available in the UK now) that will go between a Sony Alpha A77 and a Tamron lens. There seems to be some recommendations I could find, but either the product doesn't seem available anymore, or it's quite restricted; e.g. you're running on manual for AF (which isn't the end of the world if that's all I can get).

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't a Sony Alpha-mount teleconverter work? Put the TC between the camera and adapter for the Tamron?

Comment: Sony's own teleconverters are quite pricey, but surely they will do the job. Sigma makes teleconverters with Sony mount too. I don't really see the problem here.

Comment: You could try the Sigma 1.4x or 2x converters, as a cheaper alternative to Sony's, but please be aware that there are limitations to these, not being compatible for AF on many lenses...!

Answer (score 1):

The Sony TCs are designed specifically for Sony G lenses and CANNOT be used with other lenses without risk of damaging both the lens and the TC - this is due to the extremely tight tolerance (about a mm gap) between the lens' rear glass and the TC's front glass.

Likewise the new Sigma APO TCs are specifically tailored for a limited set of lenses such as the two Sigma 70-200 f/2.8 lenses. It is possible that they could work with the old or new Tamron 70-200 but I would take yours to a shop and examine them very closely, with the Tamron at each end of the zoom range, before shelling out. Tamron's own SP TCs (identical to Kenko's pro series TCs) get a wide variety of opinions, ranging from excellent to junk.

I use one of the Tamron 1.4x TCs on my Sony 100mm f/2.8 macro (making it a 140mm f/4) with fairly good results - rarely has to hunt for focus much more than the lens on its own. It does exacerbate the corner chromatic aberrations of the lens a bit, but shooting at f/8 (i.e. f/11 with the 1.4x) eliminates almost all of this.

Note that many older Tamron/Kenko 1.4x TCs and 2x TCs will not AF with digital cameras. If it has 8 contacts it should be fine. If it has 5 then steer clear.